# Attach image to oldest facebook api note.create?

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm using this code to create a simple note on behalf of a user:

```
$title   =  'Create Notes';

$content = 'I love you, I like notes';
?>
```

and:

```
$param = array(
    'method'     =>  'notes.create',
    'uid'        =>  '',
    'title'      =>  $title,
    'content'    =>  $content
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are no options to add attachments to your notes in the old REST API [`notes.create`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notes.create/) method.

I guess it's time to upgrade!